# How to use gstreamer to save a rtsp audio stream with encoding MPEG4-GENERIC

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, video-encoding

I have an rtsp stream with audio and video. I need to save the audio into a .ts file. The audio encoding is MPEG4-GENERIC. What pipeline can be used to save the audio stream? I've tried decodebin, it gives an error saying Missing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching stream via rtsp then there is no need to decode the stream to save to .ts Just depayload the stream, you can use appropriate depayloader like rtph264depay or rtpvp8depay based on you source encoding

Some thing as below to save only video,

*gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp_url ! rtph264depay ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=file.ts*

To save both video and audio, pipeline can be used as below

*gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp_url name=rtspsrc ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=file.ts rtspsrc. ! application/x-rtp,payload=97 ! rtpmp4adepay ! aacparse ! mux. -e*

You can apply depayloader and muxer as per your codec specific plugins.

Coming to error 'Missing plugin' may be your gstreamer installation in incomplete or corrupted. Please install all the modules of GStreamer like gstreamer, gst-plugins-base , gst-plugins-good, gst-plugins-bad, gst-plugins-ugly

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but this will only save the video stream the audio is not saved. I need to save both audio and video in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Chakradhar K

I have used a similar command to save an audio-video file and it's working for me.

To save both video and audio

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.68.114:5554/playlist.m3u" name=rtspsrc ! application/x-rtp,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=sintel_video.mp4 rtspsrc. ! application/x-rtp,payload=97 ! rtpmp4gdepay ! aacparse ! mux. -e

I have just changed rtpmp4adepay to rtpmp4gdepay.

and you can check more information using this command

gst-inspect-1.0 rtpmp4gdepay

Documentation: [GStreamer tools](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html?gi-language=c)